# How to deploy the code in multiple stage in Azure App services using YAML?

Tags: java, yaml, azure-web-app-service, microservices, azure-pipelines-yaml

``I have a requirement that I need to deploy Java app to the 10 app services in Azure App services, for this we have 10 different repositories for each microservices.
Currently I have deployed to dev environment using YAML pipeline and now my requirement is to deploy to test, UAT and prod environment using the same YAML pipeline.
Please suggest me how to parameterized the YAML, so that i am able to deploy using the same YAML file to all the environment.

Reference link: I follow the below link and implemented same in my YAML, but this didn't worked
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

YAML code:

parameters:

- name: targetAppService

  displayName: Target App Service

  type: string

  default: none

  values:

  - none
  - AppService1
  - AppService2
  - AppService3
  - AppService4
  - AppService5
  - AppService6
  - AppService7

pool: $(agentpool)
trigger: none
variables:

- ${{ if and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'],'Manual'), eq(parameters['targetAppService'], 'AppService1')) }}:
- template: /app-services/vars/AppService1-variables.yml
- ${{ if and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'],'Manual'), eq(parameters['targetAppService'], 'AppService2')) }}:
- template: /app-services/vars/AppService2-variables.yml
- ${{ if and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'],'Manual'), eq(parameters['targetAppService'], 'AppService3')) }}:
- template: /app-services/vars/AppService3-variables.yml
- ${{ if and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'],'Manual'), eq(parameters['targetAppService'], 'AppService4')) }}:
- template: /app-services/vars/AppService4-variables.yml
- ${{ if and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'],'Manual'), eq(parameters['targetAppService'], 'AppService5')) }}:
- template: /app-services/vars/AppService5-variables.yml
- ${{ if and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'],'Manual'), eq(parameters['targetAppService'], 'AppService6')) }}:
- template: /app-services/vars/AppService6-variables.yml
- ${{ if and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'],'Manual'), eq(parameters['targetAppService'], 'AppService7')) }}:
- template: /app-services/vars/AppService7-variables.yml
- ${{if and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'],'Manual'), eq( parameters['targetAppService'], 'none' )) }}:
- group: none
  resources:
    repositories:
    - repository: repo1
      type: git
      name: Project/repo1
    - repository: repo2
      type: git
      name: Project/repo2
    - repository: repo3
      type: git
      name: Project/repo3
    - repository: repo4
      type: git
      name: Project/repo4
    - repository: repo5
      type: git
      name: Project/repo5
    - repository: repo6
      type: git
      name: Project/repo6
    - repository: repo7
      type: git
      name: Project/repo7

- repository: templates
    type: git
    name: Project/pipeline_code_repo
    ref: master

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: "Build Java App"
  jobs:
  - template: app-services/templates/build-template.yml@templates
    parameters:
      Repository: '$(repository)@$(Buildbranch)'

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: "Deploy  Java App"
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
  - template: app-services/templates/deploy-template.yml@templates
    parameters:
      environment: $(environment)
      serviceconnection: $(serviceconnection)
      agentpool: $(agentpool)
      resourceGroup: $(resourceGroup)

Comment: So 10 microservices and 4 environments? Do you want 1 YAML file to include all services or do you want 1 YAML file per microservice? Can you share your file for 1 service, because the answer will depend on what you have to do for 1 deployment. For instance can the artefact created during the build step be deployed to all environments? Or do you have to rebuild for each environment?

Comment: @charlie V, yes Charlie, its 10 microservices and 4 environments . As of now, I have deployed these 10 microservices in Dev environment only(1 YAML file). Here, the artifact gets created during build step and then gets deployed to specific environment. Hence 1 YAML file should contain code to deploy to all the environments(Dev,Test,UAT,Prod).

Comment: And can you share what you have now?

Comment: @CharlieV - I have added the code in the description. CAn you please check.

Comment: @CharlieV - Can you please update on the above request.